# Golang Error: Undefined: http.NewSingleHostReverseProxy

Tags: http, proxy, go, reverse-proxy

I tried building a simple program using Golang, here it is:

```
package main

import (
        "net/http"
        "net/http/httputil"
        "log"
)

func main(){

        proxy := http.NewSingleHostReverseProxy( &http.URL{Scheme:"http",Host:"www.google.com",Path:"/"})

        err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", proxy)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err.String())
        }
}
```

Build:

```
go build myprogram.go
```

Output:

```
command-line-arguments
./myprogram.go:5: imported and not used: "net/http/httputil"
./myprogram.go:11: undefined: http.NewSingleHostReverseProxy
./myprogram.go:11: undefined: http.URL
./myprogram.go:15: err.String undefined (type error has no field or method String)
```

I noticed that http.NewSingleHostReverseProxy is in the "net/http/httputil" package, so why did I see such errors?
Maybe I need a specific command to build it correctly?

**EDIT**
Afterwords, here is the new working code:

```
package main

import (
        "net/http"
        "net/http/httputil"
        "net/url"
        "log"
)

func main(){

        proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy( &url.URL{Scheme:"http",Host:"www.google.com",Path:"/"})

        err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", proxy)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
        }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy` then?

Comment: @raina77ow, I replaced `http.NewSingleHostReverseProxy` with `httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy` and the error is gone, thanks. But the error with `http.URL` still occur.

Comment: Because it's actually `url.URL`, not `http.URL`. Not all the http-related functions/types are gathered in `net/http` package.

Comment: @raina77ow, Thanks! I fixed all errors. Thanks for help.

Comment: It would be nice if any of you two would answer this question so it can be marked as resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added

```
"net/url"
```

And replaced `http.NewSingleHostReverseProxy` with `httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy`, also 
`http.URL` with `url.URL`.

This is the working code:

```
package main

import (
"net/http"
"net/http/httputil"
"net/url"
"log"
)

func main(){

proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy( &url.URL{Scheme:"http",Host:"www.google.com",Path:"/"})

err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", proxy)
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
}
}
```

Thanks to  raina77ow for help.